# RegEnumValue only returning ERROR_MORE_DATA

Tags: c, windows, registry, msdn

The following code always returns error 0xEX (ERROR_MORE_DATA):
According to the documentation of MSFT (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regenumvaluea)

"If the function fails, the return value is a system error code. If there are no more values available, the function returns ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS.
If the buffer specified by lpValueName or lpData is too small to receive the value, the function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA."

I set the data length to be almog 32K, what's the issue here?

```
#define REGISTRY_VALUE 32767
int get_key_values(HKEY* key, DWORD number_of_values)
{
    DWORD values_size = REGISTRY_VALUE;
    TCHAR values[REGISTRY_VALUE]; 
    long result = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    BYTE data[REGISTRY_VALUE];
    DWORD data_length = REGISTRY_VALUE;
    DWORD counter = 0;

    for (counter = 0; counter < number_of_values; counter++) {
        values_size = MAX_VALUE_NAME;
        values[0] = '\0'; 
        result = RegEnumValue(*key, counter,
                              values, &values_size,
                              NULL, NULL,
                              data, &data_length);
        if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS) { 
            printf("data=%s\n", data);
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You failed to reinitialize `data_length` before each call, so it has the leftover value from the previous iteration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual C++ RegGetValue() fails in program where it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069085/visual-c-reggetvalue-fails-in-program-where-it-shouldnt)